# How to return Firebase promise values to graphql?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, graphql, create-react-app

So, I added Firebase to my react project. I am able to console.log() the values but, that's were i'm stuck. How can I get the valuse from the .then into graphql.

This is my settings at the top of the page.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server-express');
const express = require('express');
const firebase = require('firebase/app');
require('firebase/firestore');


const  config = {
  apiKey: "#################",
  authDomain: "#################",
  databaseURL: "#################",
  projectId: "#################",
  storageBucket: "#################",
  messagingSenderId: "#################",
  appId: "#################",
  measurementId: "#################"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

const firestore = firebase.firestore()
```

I have used this method in redux and it works. Now i'm trying to get it in graphql.

```
export const getFirebasePage = () => {

  const firbasePageRef = firestore.collection('pages');

  return firbasePageRef.get()
  .then(function(querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
          const { title, meta, sections } = doc.data();

          return {
            routeName: encodeURI(title.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()),
            id: doc.id,
            meta,
            sections,
            title
          };

      });
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
  });

}
```

After the promise is successful then I would like be able to add the values to graphql like so.

```
//resolver
const Query = {
  page: (root, {id}) => ValueFromPromise.pages.get(id)
}


//schema
type Query {
  page(id: ID!): Page
}

type Page{
  id:ID!
  routName: String!,
  meta: [Episode!]!,
  sections: [Episode!]!,
  title, String!
}
```

How can I do this? Can it be done inside a resolver like so:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    pages: firbasePageRef.get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        return querySnapshot.forEach(function( doc) {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            const { title, meta, sections } = doc.data();
            const data = {
              routeName: encodeURI(title.toLowerCase()),
              id: doc.id,
              meta,
              sections
            };
            console.log(data); //The correct data is login here. I think I need a resolver or another .then. This is were i'm stuck!
            return data;
        });
    }).then(function(results){
       return results;
    })
  }
};
```

My query in the graphql playground look like this

```
query{
  pages{
    title
  }
}
```

And my results looks like this

```
{
  "data": {
    "pages": null
  }
}
```

When I log the revolvers I get this

```
{ Query: { pages: Promise { <pending> } } }
```

Answer (score 1):

With some hard work and determination I was able to get it solved.
Within the `.then` function I defined a new array call `let newQueryData = [];` and within the `.forEach` function I appended the new array `newQueryData.push(data);` and finally I returned the new array `return newQueryData;`. I didn't need another `.then`. Here is my final code.

I took out most of the code from the graphql resolver like so;

```
const firbasePageRef = firestore.collection('pages');
const getPagePromise = firbasePageRef.get()
.then((querySnapshot) => {
  let newQueryData = [];
    const queryData = querySnapshot.forEach(function( doc) {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        const { title, meta, sections } = doc.data();
        const data = {
          routeName: encodeURI(title.toLowerCase()),
          id: doc.id,
          meta,
          sections,
          title
        };
        newQueryData.push(data);
    })

    return newQueryData;

});
```

Next I edited the graphql resolver like so:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    pages: () => getPagePromise
  }
};
```

Now in graphql playground this is my results!

```
{
  "data": {
    "pages": [
      {
        "title": "Home Page"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Guys I hope this helps anyone that is having the same or a similar problem. This is Firebase to graphql.